# My Malborn runs into a sign and disappears? Why?!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So... I found him after Diplomatic Immunity, and killed the assassin for him, so he could escape Windhelm and go to Morrowind.  I tried to follow him to the border to help him through, but he went North-East (rather than South-East, towards the gate at the border).  Eventually he ran into a sign a little ways NE down the trail from Windhelm, and just disappeared?!  Well, that was the second time.  The first time, he went NE and ran into a tree and disappeared.  I went back to my last save to try again, and that's when he ran into the little waist-high plaque/sign thing, and was gone!  I haven't been able to successfully get him to where he's going.  Why?

(It's the Xbox 360 version, if that helps)

Also... can one marry Malborn?  He's resisting all my advances, even with the Amulet of Mara!

Answer (score 2):

Malborn is supposed to run south out of Windhelm and then turn east near the stables. The road will veer northeast towards Morrowind. Once he reaches the pedestal with the [Decree of Monument](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Decree_of_Monument) book on it, he will disappear. If he goes anywhere else, it might be an error in Skyrim’s calculation of NPC routes.

And no, you cannot [marry](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage) Malborn, presumably because he disappears from the game at the end of the [Thalmor Assassin](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Find_the_Thalmor_Assassin) quest.

Comment: Following Malborn is fairly disappointing. Instead of watching him run off into the distance all the way into Morrowind, he just vanishes before he even quite reaches the border. I feel like making a mod that moves his destination out of sight a long way into Morrowind, but I haven’t done it.

Comment: Oh? That's as far as he goes?  Okay... yeah, that is a little disappointing.  I thought he was going to go through the gate on the East side of Skyrim... Not just disappear!  I'd heard other people talk about how they had to follow him, and kill a bunch of guards that were at the border, so I thought I had to help him if he was actually going to get over.

Comment: @LarryWren There shouldn’t be any guards at the border, but the bandits at [Traitor’s Post](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Traitor%27s_Post) might spot you and Malborn as you run past. I feel like Bethesda could have designed that part of the quest better. :-/